# Base table or view not found: Table doesn't exist ERROR while trying to insert some data

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-9, laravel-migrations

I have a Laravel 9 project and in the migration of one of the tables, I would like to insert some data as well when creating the table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tag_filters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('tag_name');
        $table->string('tag_uri')->nullable();
        $table->string('tag_color');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_parent')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('tag_parent')->references('id')->on('tag_filters')->onDelete('cascade');

        DB::table('tag_filters')->insert(
            array(
                [
                    'tag_name' => 'javascript',
                    'tag_color' => 'f9bc64',
                ],
            )
        );
    });
}
```

But now when I run the migrations by saying `php artisan migrate`, I get this error:

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'forum.tag_filters' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `tag_filters`...**

So what's going wrong here?

How can I properly insert some data when creating a new table via the Migrations in Laravel?

Comment: use seeders https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/seeding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel creates the `tag_filters` table after the closure has been executed. So right now you're trying to insert a record in the table that does not exists yet.
Executing the insert statement after the closure will work.

```
Schema::create('tag_filters', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('tag_name');
    $table->string('tag_uri')->nullable();
    $table->string('tag_color');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_parent')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('tag_parent')->references('id')->on('tag_filters')->onDelete('cascade');
});

DB::table('tag_filters')->insert(
    array(
        [
            'tag_name' => 'javascript',
            'tag_color' => 'f9bc64',
        ],
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
Atisan::call('db:seed', [
   '--class' => (seedername)'
   '--force' => true
]);
```

instead of:

```
 DB::table('tag_filters')->insert(
            array(
                [
                    'tag_name' => 'javascript',
                    'tag_color' => 'f9bc64',
                ],
            )
        );
```

then you will trigger the seeder you call automatically when migrating.
but you have to create the seeder class and fill it in!

Answer (score 0):

always always use seeders to insert data into tables and migrations to create or alter them